# Expected Value Of a Random Grid That Contains Multipliers

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, expected-value, recreational-mathematics, means

I am a software developer and recently came across this problem when working on a hobby project, and my knowledge of probability is too small to solve this.

I have a bag that contains 5 negative ones, 5 zeros, 10 ones, 5 twos, 5 threes. The tiles are set randomly on a 5 by 5 grid with 5 tiles left in the bag. The threes in the bag also multiply all 8 of the adjacent squares by 2 (A number is multiplied by $2^n$ adjacent 3's). What is the best way to calculate the expected value of the grid for any known bag that can contain a random amount of any numbers? Bonus points if it can handle any size (and rectangular shape) of grid.

Eg. Bag ( 2 1 3 3 3 ), Grid Value: 27

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
3&2&1&-1&1\\
\hline
1&1&0&0&-1\\
\hline 
1&0&3&2&2\\
\hline
-1&0&-1&2&1\\
\hline
1&-1&1&1&0
\end{array}$$

Without the multiplier, the solution is quite simple:

> The number of values in the grid (25) × The sum of all of the numbers in the bag / the number of numbers in the bag. Or $(n * s) / a$

Since they do not interact, the fact they are in a grid does not even matter. For the same reason, it's not that useful for solving this problem, but I thought I would mention it as a start.

[A kinda related question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207655/accounting-for-chance-changes-in-averages?noredirect=1#comment8734793_4207655)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks I edited the question, this better?

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Thank you.

Comment: Clarifying the rules here: So any tile that is horizontally, vertically, or diagonally adjacent to a $3$ gets its value doubled. If a number is adjacent to two threes, its value is quadrupled; adjacent to three threes, octupled; etc.  Is that correct? And, for instance, two adjacent 3s would both get doubled?

Comment: @paw88789 All correct.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this does NOT solve the problem stated. I implicitly assume that if a value is next to $n$ threes, it is multiplied by $n + 1$. However, OP clarified in the comments that the value is multiplied by $2^n$ if it is next to $n$ threes. I'm not sure how to fix this.

This is actually a rather simple problem (or rather, the complexity is deceptive). The problem boils down to calculating the expected value of the sum of elements adjacent to each three.

By linearity of expectation, it suffices to calculate the expected sum of elements adjacent to a given 3, then multiply by the number of 3s.

Now the expected sum of the neighbors of a given 3 is equal to the expected number of neighbors, times the expected value of each given neighbor. This is because no matter how many neighbors a 3 has, the expected value of a given neighbor is constant.

Let's take the case of an $m \times m$ grid with $n$ copies of 3 and a total number of bag elements $M \geq m \geq 2$. Then the expected value of a neighbor of 3 will be $\frac{S - 3}{M - 1}$, where $S$ is the sum of all elements in the bag.

Now for calculating the expected number of neighbors of a given 3. To do this, note that there is a $\frac{4}{M}$ chance of the 3 being in a corner, a $\frac{4(m - 2)}{M}$ chance of $m$ being on an edge, and a $\frac{(m - 2)^2}{M}$ chance of the 3 being in the middle. If the 3 is in a corner, it has only 3 neighbours. On an edge, the 3 will have 5 neighbours. There is also a chance the 3 won't make it onto the board of $\frac{M - m^2}{M}$, in which case the 3 will have zero neighbors. This gives us an expected value of $3 \frac{4}{M} + 5 \frac{4(m - 2)}{M} + 8 \frac{(m - 2)^2}{M}$.

So the expected sum of the neighbours of all threes will be $n \cdot \frac{S - 3}{M} \cdot (3 \frac{4}{M} + 5 \frac{4(m - 2)}{M} + 8 \frac{(m - 2)^2}{M})$.

To answer the original problem, we must add the expected sum of the (unadjusted by 3-doubling) grid back in, which is $\frac{S m^2}{M}$.

So the final answer is

$$
\frac{S m^2}{M} + n \cdot \frac{S - 3}{M} \cdot (3 \frac{4}{M} + 5 \frac{4(m - 2)}{M} + 8 \frac{(m - 2)^2}{M})
$$

Comment: What about a grid of uneven size like 5x4? Also thanks for this great answer.

Comment: @GameDungeon With a grid of uneven size, the only thing that changes are the probabilities of being at a corner/edge/middle location. The idea is exactly the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks again :)

Comment: I am not sure this correctly takes into account the situation where a number is adjacent to two $3$s, in which case it should be quadrupled- I think this way of counting triples it instead?

Comment: One last question (I'm not that good with this kind of math) What is the capital M vs the lowercase m?

Comment: @GameDungeon Capital $M$ = total number of tiles originally in the bag. Lower case $m$ = the side length of the grid.

Comment: @MarkSaving Well another last thing, does it address what sal pointed out?

Comment: @GameDungeon Unfortunately, it seems it does not (and thus this doesn't solve the problem). Sorry about that - I should have read the comments more thoroughly before posting. See edit for details.

Comment: @MarkSaving Well thanks for the answer anyway, while not entirely answering the question, it does provide a lot of good insight into achieving that goal.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach--in the sense of requiring the least mathematics--is via simulation.  You would program random permutations and compute the value of the grid for each one; with sufficiently large samples, the expectation would be reasonably close to the exact value, and you can also get an estimate of the standard deviation of the value.

My code in *Mathematica*:

```
b = Sort[Flatten[Join[Table[Range[4] - 1, 5], Table[1, 10]]]];
t[m_] := Take[m, {Max[1, #[[1]] - 1], Min[5, #[[1]] + 1]}, {Max[1, #[[2]] - 1], 
         Min[5, #[[2]] + 1]}] & /@ Position[m, 3]
s[m_] := Total[Flatten[t[m]]] + Total[Flatten[m]] - 3 Count[Flatten[m], 3]
d = ParallelTable[s[Partition[RandomSample[b, 25], 5]], 10^6];
{Mean[d], Variance[d]}
```

This produces $10^6$ simulations and computes the overall mean and variance.  Note the following:

- My algorithm shows that the correct score for the grid in your question is $38$, not $39$.
- My instance of running this code produced a mean of $63.9687$.

An exact calculation would be problematic, since the number of such grids is quite large, even after accounting for symmetries and repeated elements.

The conditional means and variances for each base total ranging from $25$ to $40$ are approximately:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
\text{base} & \text{mean} & \text{variance} \\
\hline
 25 & 25. & 0. \\
 26 & 31.4203 & 4.60442 \\
 27 & 36.0449 & 18.0836 \\
 28 & 40.4705 & 19.7906 \\
 29 & 44.906 & 31.9896 \\
 30 & 49.4376 & 36.9694 \\
 31 & 53.8249 & 47.2579 \\
 32 & 58.3649 & 55.2471 \\
 33 & 62.7921 & 61.3061 \\
 34 & 67.0464 & 69.8355 \\
 35 & 71.4379 & 73.5359 \\
 36 & 75.1243 & 69.9286 \\
 37 & 77.7472 & 68.0978 \\
 38 & 79.9451 & 67.8064 \\
 39 & 82.2345 & 66.5388 \\
 40 & 85.338 & 70.5698 \\
\end{array}$$
This is based on $10^7$ simulations.

Comment: I was aware I could do this, but I need to combine this with some other math, and it's quite computation heavy. I would much prefer the mathematical solution if you know it. If no-one else can find a better answer in a few days I'll mark it correct and do this.

Comment: Also, I got the number wrong the grid I'll be using is 5 x 4, small enough for the exact calculation I believe. I'll leave it as 5x5 in the question though.