# Accounting for Chance Changes in Averages

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics, means, simulation

*Moderators: I really don't know what to name this or what tags to put so feel free to edit this*

I'm a software developer, and in my spare time, I wanted to create a computer program to play a card game. I want it to simulate the future to see the best moves. That is where this problem comes from.

I have a known set that can contain any amount and value of number. If I randomly select 5 different numbers to add together, on average what should their value be?

Now for the hard part. Let's say I want to do this three times, but when played -2's remove themselves after being added and 6's add a 0 to the set. And after being added all numbers are returned to the set (except the -2's). Given a random set, what is the expected sum on each draw?

The issue is that a number removed or added affects the values of all future sets.

```
                 start
                /  |  \
   number removed  |  number added
    /    |  \      |     /    |    \
  add   rem Nothing Changes  rem   add
 / | \ / | \    /  |  \     / | \ / | \
........................................
```

Each of those possibilities branches off each time I add the values until we get a statistical mess I don't know how to deal with.

As an example set: (-2 -2 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 6 6 6 6)

I know for the first draw the odds are:

> The number of numbers drawn (5) × The sum of all of the numbers in the set (37) / the number of numbers in the set (15). Or $(n * s) / a$,  Or $(5*37)/15 = 12.333...$

But after that, I don't know how to deal with the branching paths.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to parse.  Is the goal to find the expected sum on draw 1, draw 2, and draw 3, given the initial values in your list?

Comment: @f3qgrgdf  Yes it is.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: What's the difference between "the number of numbers in the set" and "the number of values in the set" ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I think he means that he has a list of numbers $x_{1},\ldots, x_{n}$ and is selecting $5$ elements from the list without replacement.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Oh, sorry, that was a bad rewording of a previous question of mine I have since answered, I'll fix that.

Comment: Just to be clear, each draw consists of picking out 5 numbers from a set, then returning them to the set except -2's which are not returned, then finally add a 0 to the set for each 6 that was picked? And you want to know the expected sum of those 5 numbers at n-th draw, given a starting set?

Comment: @Vepir Yes, exactly.